# Python pysimplegui calendar - dynamically update default_date_m_d_y

Tags: python, calendar, default, pysimplegui

Is there a way to use pysimpleGUI to update the date that a `calendarbutton` loads to, based on user input? For example, using the below code, if a user enters a date in the first box, then the calendar should load to that date when the "Calendar 1" button is pressed.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(readonly=True, enable_events=True, key='INPUT 1'),
     sg.CalendarButton('Calendar 1', close_when_date_chosen=True, format='%Y-%m-%d', key='Calendar 1', default_date_m_d_y=(9,12,2023))],
]

window = sg.Window('Calendar Button', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event)
    if event == 'Input 1':
        print(values[event])

window.close()
```

I've tried using a datetime variable as an input to `default_date_m_d_y`, but it doesn't update. It always loads the calendar to the first value of that variable, even if I update it within the event. Do I need to somehow refresh it or something?

`[sg.CalendarButton("Select Start Date:", close_when_date_chosen=True, target='-START_DATE-', no_titlebar=False, size=15, format ='%m/%d/%Y', default_date_m_d_y = (StartDateGUI.month,StartDateGUI.day,StartDateGUI.year), key='StartCal')`

Thanks for any pointers here. I've been scouring the Internet and documentation but can't see how I can update `default_date_m_d_y`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the attribute of `element.calendar_default_date_M_D_Y` directly.

```py
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='INPUT 1'),
     sg.CalendarButton('Calendar 1', close_when_date_chosen=True, format='%Y-%m-%d', key='Calendar 1', default_date_m_d_y=(8,10,2022))],
    [sg.StatusBar("", size=(5, 1), expand_x=True, key='Status')],
]

window = sg.Window('Calendar Button', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    window['Status'].update("")
    if event == 'INPUT 1':
        new_date = values[event]
        try:
           date = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
        except ValueError:
           window['Status'].update("Incorrect data format, should be MM-DD-YYYY")
           continue
        window['Calendar 1'].calendar_default_date_M_D_Y = (date.month, date.day, date.year)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this - 'calendar_default_date_M_D_Y' is exactly what I was looking for. I've now got this working on some parts of my project, but struggling to get it working based off of the input field. I've run your example, but the date I enter doesn't appear to be loaded when I click the "Calendar 1" button. Please could you help me to understand what I should enter as input in your example in order for this to work? Thanks again!

Comment: There should be error message `Incorrect data format, should be MM-DD-YYYY` shown on the bottom status if wrong format.